# App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile vs Development Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got two provisioning profiles: App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile and Development Provisioning Profile. The question is rather easy but I need a clarification. I guess that the code signed with the App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile won't run on the devices I normally use for development. Am I right? And is there any possibility to run this code on my devices?

P.S. I know there are similar questions. However, no one has asked whether it is possible to run code signed with the App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile on the devices normally used for development.

The reason why I am asking is that I am integrating Push Notifications with Parse.com (which is in beta) and I'd like to test if their service works well in the production environment.

**The Answer** (thanks to Kheldar):

*App Store provisioning profiles do not allow for a distribution built application to be installed on an Apple device. To install your distribution ready application on a device, you must create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile.*

It can be also checked in the Organizer:
[image]

Comment: However, that answer is incorrect. AppStore builds CAN be installed on devices, and we have done this many times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The development profile serves for developing and testing on your devices.

The distribution profile serves for making your IPA file, sign it and send it to Apple.

It is clearly marked that you cannot run it on devices, unless you have an Ad Hoc distribution profile:

*App Store provisioning profiles do not allow for a distribution built application to be installed on an Apple device. To install your distribution ready application on a device, you must create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile.*

Comment: Yeap, I know it. So there is no way in running the code signed with distribution profile other then purchasing the app in the App Store after app's approval?

Comment: As I understand it, either you use the Ad Hoc profile, either you create a coupon as explained in the iTunes Connect pages (and use it on your devices). Check this: http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html

Answer (score 3):

Back in 2014 when this question was asked, and perhaps a bit later, it was perfectly possible to install an application signed with an AppStore profile on device, provided that the matching AdHoc profile was already installed. This subsequently changed, and it is no longer possible (2019) to install an app signed with an AppStore profile except via download from Apple (e.g. via TestFlight).

Answer (score 0):

When you build and run the code using the distribution profile, it will get installed on the device, but will not allow you to debug it. Pls note that the device must be a valid one included in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is upload the ipa file to itunesconnect with distribution certificate and use TestFlight to confirm the push notifications.

Answer (score -1):

it is not possible to code signed with the App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile on the devices. If it is App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile it is possible to install in devices by dragging to iTunes.

Comment: What happens once the app is accepted in App Store? Then, push will work? You will have matching provisioning profiles then on device and on parse.com Right?