# Steps to configure ‘App store distribution provision profile’ for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios

The core feature of our app heavily relies on 'Apple Push Notification'. So far, our app works great with Ad-Hoc distribution provisioning profile.

Now, we are in process of submitting our app to App store for review.

My questions are

1) Do i have to create 'App store distribution provisioning profile' for push notification ? ( I already have ‘Ad-Hoc distribution provisioning profile’ )

2) Do i need to create new App-ID or can i reuse App ID created for Ad-Hoc distribution ?

3) Is it possible to test our app signed with 'App store distribution provisioning profile' on actual device to ensure push notification works ?

Kindly help us! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
--Prem

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes you have to create a Distribution profile

2- Every app uses the same ID so no need to create a new one

3- Yes you can

Comment: Thanks antf. Just out of curiosity, how do you install app signed with 'App store distribution provisioning profile' on device ?

Comment: Thanks again antf. I am pretty convinced that you cannot test your app signed with 'Appstore distribution provisioning profile'. Here is note from Apple :  "App Store provisioning profiles do not allow for a distribution built application to be installed on an Apple device. To install your distribution ready application on a device, you must create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile. " Here is a link which supports this fact - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560689/app-store-distribution-provisioning-profile-vs-development-provisioning-profile

Comment: You can do a trick which is after submitting it for revision you request a Promotion Code, this allows you to install it with the distribution profile. I ma not sure if the promotion version can be downloaded before the release of the app but I remember that once read in the Apple documentation that you can do so, haven't tried it though. One more thing don't be worried about testing the distribution profile, it is just a signature, both AdHoc and distribution use the same APN server which is the release one; there is nothing that affects your code.

Comment: Thank you very much antf. I will definately give a shot about your suggestion pertaining to Promotion Code. Will update the post about my appstore submission experience. I truly appreciate your help. Thanks again.